# How to automatically add new strings to Localizable.strings for all languages?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, internationalization

I am trying to add a key-value pair to my Localizable.strings file and have it automatically update the other files that I have for different languages.

Can this be done, or do I have to manually add it to the other language files?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [Library](https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch). It has beautiful documentation so I'm not adding the description here. It automates a few basic tasks that are simple and repetitive in nature. Hope this helps.